# AWS Lambda in java "Process exited before completing request"

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function using java. 1st time it is execute properly, but when I run lambda function 2nd time it is showing me below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: d73aab19-25ef-458b-a436-b6c2e10a18cb Process exited before completing request"
}
```

After the error it is working fine. I don't know why this error come after successfully build 1st build.

Below is the source code when I added it give me issue else working fine, but I need this code:

```
FontsLoader.clearCache();
File fdir = new File("/tmp");
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(fdir);
TransferManager xfer_mgr = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().build();

try {
    MultipleFileDownload xfer = xfer_mgr.downloadDirectory(
        bucket_name, "font", new File("/tmp"));
    xfer.waitForCompletion();
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}


String[] fontdir = {"/tmp"};


//apply font into PPTX
FontsLoader.loadExternalFonts(fontdir);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post your code or stack trace. There are several causes due to which you may get this error. May need to print the details and debug through cloudwatch logs.

Comment: What is the time out setting for the lambda? Default is 15 seconds I guess. Increase if you need to